# ¿como crear un diccionario de datos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tengo esto en mi js, el problema es que en  mi base de datos cada columna es un mes y guardo la ciudad por ejemplo. ciudad: en, columna1(enero):12 etc..

lo que quiero primero es cachar el mes actual para imprimir el numero que tiene, lo que se me ocurrio fue hacer un diccionario de datos para checar en que mes estamos y asi cuando recorra mi array nadamas concatenarle , pero al momento de imprimir mes1 me marca indefinido que estoy haciendo mal, tal vez el diccionario?

```
 var f=new Date();
 var mes = f.getMonth()+1;

 var mesess = new Array();
      mesess[1] ="en";
      mesess[2] ="fe";
      mesess[3] ="ma";
      mesess[4] ="ab";
      mesess[5] ="may";
      mesess[6] ="ju";
      mesess[7] ="jul";
      mesess[8] ="ag";
      mesess[9] ="se";
      mesess[10] ="oc";
      mesess[11] ="no";
      mesess[12] ="di";


 console.log(mesess);
 mes2=mesess[mes];

 for(var i=0; i<json.Data.meta.length;i++)
 {
   if(json.Data.meta[i].ciudad=='En')
   {

     mes1=json.Data.meta[i].mes2;

   }
 }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es algo como esto

```
mes1=json.Data.meta[i].en;
```

dependiendo del numero de mes que sea por ejemplo si en mi `var mes = f.getMonth()+1;` es 1(Es el mes de enero) entonces que me ponga `mes1=json.Data.meta[i].en;` si el mes es 2 (es el mes de febrero) entonces que me ponga `mes1=json.Data.meta[i].fe;` no se si me explique

Comment: ¿Qué es json.Data.meta?

Comment: ¿Para que vas a utilizar el diccionario? ¿Estás seguro que con las funciones de formato de Date() no son suficientes?

Comment: hola de acuerdo a @AaronRomero puedes usar las funciones Date() y tambien si quieres los meses en español usa la libreira https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize

Comment: @PabloLozano json.Data.meta con eso accedo a la información que necesito

Comment: @AaronRomero si para no poner muchos else if y solo decirle que si el numero de mes es 1 entonces imprimir lo de enero

Comment: Para mí el código  no tiene mucho sentido (creas muchos datos que luego no usas), así que no entiendo realmente qué quieres hacer

Comment: ya pude resolverlo, lo que realmente quiero es que si este mes es diciembre dentro de mi if me ponga mes1=json.Data.meta[i].di para sacar el valor de diciembre, ahora si es enero entonces dentro de mi if me ponga  mes1=json.Data.meta[i].en

Answer (score 0):

Tu objetivo es obtener el nombre del mes en base al mes de la columna.

```js
const mesNombres= ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio",
  "Julio", "Augusto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"
];

const d = new Date();
document.write(`El mes actual es ${mesNombres[d.getMonth()]}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco el contenido de **json.Data.meta** tal cual lo veo debe ser una array parecido a lo siguiente:

```
[
  {"en": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_A"},
  {"fe": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_B"},
  {"ma": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_C"},
  {"ab": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_D"},
  {"may": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_E"}
]
```

Basado en esto, podría decir que el contenido para **Enero** esta en la posición 0 y no en la 1 (ya que es un array)

```
// la variable json_data representara el contenido de json.Data.meta
let json_data = [{ "en": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_A" }, { "fe": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_B" }, { "ma": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_C" }, { "ab": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_D" }, { "may": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_E" }, { "ju": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_F" }, { "jul": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_G" }, { "ag": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_H" }, { "se": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_I" }, { "oc": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_J" }, { "no": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_K" }, { "di": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_L" }];

// Tendremos un array de las llaves existentes en json_data deben estar estrictamente 
ordenados
let llave_meses = ["en", "fe", "ma", "ab", "may", "ju", "jul", "ag", "se", "oc", "no", "di"];

// Obtenemos el mes actual
let mes = new Date().getMonth();

// obtenemos la llave del mes
let llave_mes = llave_meses[mes];

// Sin necesidad de iterar obtenemos el valor del json_data, la prueba es cuando mes = 11
console.log(json_data[mes]) // salida -> { "di": "valor_x", "ciudad": "ciudad_L" }

// El valor de la llave
console.log(json_data[mes][llave_mes]); // salida -> valor_x

// La condicion que esta dentro de tu for
if (json_data[mes].ciudad == 'En') {
    mes1 = json_data[mes][llave_mes];
}
```

Dado que tus referencias de los meses (las llaves dentro de tu json.Data.meta) son distintos, para acceder a ellos desde javascript debes tratarlos como array (la bondad de un object en js), por eso en lugar de:

```
json.Data.meta[i].mes2;
```

Debes usar:

```
json.Data.meta[i][llave_mes];
```

Espero logre resolver tu problema, o te des alguna idea, ya que desconocemos la estructura de **json.Data.meta**, si puedes publicar mayor información o ser un poco más explícito la comunidad te lo agradecerá.